# How do I position an List element to the absoulute center of the Page?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

basically i think its an easy task but i cannot get it right

I have a navigation bar with 5 elements. The third one, which is an round image should be in the center of the webbpage. but because the 4th list element is slightly longer (the word means opening hrs) it does shift to the right a bit. So altough my list (navigation bar) is in the middle of the webpage, the logo itself isnt. I tried a lot but couldnt figure it out.

heres the fiddle:

```
    <header>
<nav>
<ul class="navi">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallerie</a></li>

    <li><img class="logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/72/Turkey_emblem_round.png" href="#" alt="LS-Lounge"></li>

    <li><a href="#">Öffnungszeiten</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
</ul>

</nav>
</header>
```

css here:

```
    nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font-family: 'Lobster', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #171717;
    text-align: center;

}

ul .navi {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;

}

.logo {
    display: block;
    height: 10vh;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

.navi {

}

.navi li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 20;

}

.navi li a{

    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 4vh;
    position: relative;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/emw3b854/

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox would work (You may need to remove the space in you css "ul .navi"  should be "ul.navi"

```
ul.navi {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
  display: flex;    
}

.navi li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 20;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Added demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/u0v6x5e3/